# How to remove what appears to be a top margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

While building my sidebar I noticed that my page content seems to have a top margin (52px of body when I inspect the page), but I don't know why? I'm going to make my sidebar pop out, but I want my '.page-content' to be full height.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXKEpE

CSS:

```
.page-content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:black;
}

.toggle{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:30px;
    color:black;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    z-index:2;
    left:200px;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:120px;
    padding:30px;
    background:#333;
    z-index:0;
}

li{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: atialiased;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#sidebartoggler{
    display:none;}

#sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .toggle{
    left: 15px;
}

#sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .page-content{
    padding-left: 180px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler" name="" value="" />

<div class="page-wrap">

    <label for="sidebartoggler" class="toggle">☰</label>

    <div class="page-content">...</div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Clients</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding content to your page? Instead of the three dots? You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

(that's always a good idea...)

Comment: Ok this works on codepen, but it had no effect on chrome or firefox.. hmm.

Comment: Actually, thanks it works! My head tag wasn't closed properly.